# What to know what is Default password for Use Development mode for Simulator BB 10 dev alpha?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator, eclipse-adt

I installed BB 10 dev alpha in VM Ware. For play book i found that it was playbook as password for use development mode what is password for BB 10 dev alpha.

I am not able to connect to Simulator while running my app in qnx and even in Android ADT (Eclipse) while running to Blackberry Summulitor using Blackberry Android Runtine tool to Abnroid ADT.

After installation of BB 10 in VMware use development mode is asking password. It come on by default. So I want to know default password of it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no default password. Just click OK with an empty password box.